# How to call javascript alert on hyperlink's click with a message cotained single quote inside?

Tags: javascript, c#

I am stuck in an issue with javascript. I am using C# to write a hyperlink which can call a javascript to show an alert message. See the code below to know how it's done:

First of all this is the code written by C# from server side:

```
//Server side code    
string myHyperlink = "<a href='#' onclick=\"alert('I'm not me.');\">Click Me!</a>";
```

When generated by client browser, I see the code as below:

```
//Client side code    
<a href="#" onclick="alert('I'm not me.');">Click Me!</a>
```

The client code can not call javascript alert when I click the hyperlink. Be cause the javascript code doesn't work.

**The issue here is:** The single quote inside the word "I'm" tear a part the parameter inside alert message. Thus the javascript cannot run, and the message cannot be shown when I click on the hyperlink.

**The problem here is:** The javascript cannot recognize the different between single quote inside the message and the surrounded quote of message.

**Requirement:** How can I define a single quote inside another single quote in javascript parameter?

Regards,

Dung Tri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quote on client-side, which means you need to escape a `\` before the quote on the server-side, e.g.

```
string myHyperlink = "<a href='#' onclick=\"alert('I\\'m not me.');\">Click Me!</a>";
```

Will print:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('I\'m not me.');">Click Me!</a>
```

Comment: This should do the trick! Thanks for your answer. I will mask it as the best answer within next 7 minutes.